# Summernote didn't upload file on server nor didn't displayed on the editor when I write the sample code, what should I do?

Tags: jquery, summernote

I can not get summercode to display images on editor nor sent to server. I've read the official documentation and no success.

I have tried official guide from summernote, and also another solution on stackoverflow.
If I delete the onImageUpload callbacks I got images on editor. And I still confused with how to make inserted image sent to server (I'm sure it's get success response in the POST request).
(I prefer answer in pure PHP on how to upload and not using framework).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        height: "300px",
        dialogsInBody: true,
        callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: function(files) {
                console.log("Sending image file");
                uploadFile(files[0]);
            }
        }
    });

    function uploadFile(file) {
        data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", file);

        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/ngetest/assets/images/",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(url) {
                console.log("image file sent!");
                $('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", url);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus+" "+errorThrown);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Here is the permission

```
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jun  4 23:06 assets
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1589 Jun  4 23:41 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  498 Jun  4 23:06 test.php
```

Here is the hierarchy

```sh
.:
assets  index.html  test.php

./assets:
images

./assets/images:
```

This is the entire HTML file except the script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.8/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
        <label for="summernote"><h1>Content</h1></label>
        <textarea id="summernote" class="summernote" name="contents">
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
    </form>
    </div>
```

The error thrown when is error Not found when I run those code. And The file is sent when I change

```
http://localhost/ngetest/assets/images/ to http://localhost/ngetest/ 
or 
http://localhost/ngetest/test.php
```

I expect if the onImageUpload method failed it still display the images on the editor but it didn't and it didn't get into server directory

```
http://localhost/ngetets/assets/images/
```

May a bit late. But this is the content of test.php

```php
<?php
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif');
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)) {
        echo "AN ERROR OCCURED - INVALID IMAGE";
        exit;
    }
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'assets/images'.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
        echo 'http://localhost/ngetest/assets/images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        exit;
    }
}
echo 'AN ERROR OCCURED';
exit;
```

Comment: The links you were added are not working. when you add a link to your question or answer need to properly working one. or you can change it to as code.

Comment: I didn't mean to add a localhost link, it just for informational purpose. I just want to tell that I have already create POST request handler.

Comment: I just edited my post, thanks.

Comment: ok. keep it forward when you post something.